# Plotting 3D Bar Chart with Plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to plot a 3d bar chart like in [this example](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Eempet/15255/plotly-3d-barchart-or-histogram3d-for-2d/#/) but I can not or dont know how to use the code for my data. This is how my data looks like:

```
z = np.array([[ -10.,  -40.,    0.,   20.,   10.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
   [   0.,  -50.,  -60.,  -20.,   20.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
   [ -60., -140.,  -90.,  -20.,   20.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
   [ 190.,  -70., -240.,   20.,   20.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
   [ 430.,   70., -380.,  -20.,   20.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
   [ 170.,    0., -280., -110.,   20.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
   [  20.,   10.,  -90.,  -80.,   20.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
   [  20.,   20.,   20.,   20.,   20.,    0.,    0.,    0.]])
```

This is how it shoud look like but with my data and a grid of 8x8:

[image]

My z-values represent the height/depth of the bins. So in total I would have 8x8 bins on this 3D plot.

I want to use [Plotly](https://plotly.com/) because the plot will be embedded in Plotly Dash and should be interactive.
So how do I need to change my data fromat to use the code from [this example](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Eempet/15255/plotly-3d-barchart-or-histogram3d-for-2d/#/) or is there another possibility to get such a plot in plotly?

Comment: It shows that this plot has been implemented using plotly only as per link you provided

Comment: @Karthik yes, but now I want to use my data (see the code-block in the question) to create such a plot.

Comment: @Karthik do you have an idea how this could be solved?

Comment: I feel your data is not related to graph. Your x,y,z axis length should be equal whereas here your z is way to big than x,y.

Comment: Yes, maybe I have to edit the question. I only want to plot my z-values. So a grid of size 8x8 like my z array and the depths/heights of the bins are the values in z. So the height of the first bin in corner [0,0] woud be -10.

Comment: I still feel your array is still not appropriate. I would suggest you to look at this https://pythonprogramming.net/3d-bar-chart-matplotlib-tutorial/ .Though it is achieved using matplotlib but it is interactive and it can be integrated to plotly dash too.

Comment: I know that my array does not fit for the code in the link, thats why I am asking on how to make it work and how I need to change my array. Thank you for sharing the link but I already tried that. I was not able to integrate it to a dash app. Could you share your code?

Comment: Sorry @smMg I am not much into dash . But here is an example that may help you in integrating matplotlib with dash https://github.com/4QuantOSS/DashIntro/blob/master/notebooks/Tutorial.ipynb

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/AymericFerreira/Plotly_barchart3D).

Comment: @TanmayaMeher Thank you this helped me to get a 3d bar chart in plotly Dash!